# Node.js falsely claims port is in use

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run node.js http server and fail as node.js thinks the port is in use. However, checking the port list with netstat shows that the port is free. Trying any other port also results in the same error:

```
var activePort = +process.argv[2];
var serverEndpoint = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
});
serverEndpoint.listen(activePort);

{ [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::30009]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 30009 }
```

I am however running multiple same processes (just with a different port number) using `forever` - I'm thinking this may have some relation to the error.

Comment: What happens if you run just one instance of it? I've never had a false report from node about ports being in use.

Comment: Uhhh, I don't think this is a false report.  If it says EADDRINUSE, then there's already something running on that port.  You should use OS services to see what is running on that port.

Comment: @AndersBornholm First 8 instances of the script run fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 Like I said, netstat does not identify the port being in use, while it does correctly identify other used ports.

Comment: Where's your real code that starts instances on separate ports?

Comment: Exactly, the port is hard coded in your example - so it's obviously not the actual code running ;-)

Comment: Updated my code example in the main question. The script is a few thousand lines, of course this is a simplified example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the ports were really in use. My system was heavily in use so most of my ephemeral port range was being actively used. I was also trying to create node.js ports in my ephemeral port range. Because of that Node.js would randomly fail, but netstat would not show the port being in use anymore after just a few seconds.

I adjusted my ephemeral port range (sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range) and Node no longer complains about ports being in use.

Comment: netstat -a should help you determine if the port is in use and what is using it. This should work across most o/ses

Comment: The issue was that the port was in use intermittently, so netstat did not show it when I was looking, but it was often in use when Node tried to access it. I guess it was just pure (un)luck that I did not see it.